# Deleted page is unsuccessfully crawled and a 404 appears

Tags: wordpress, seo, google-search-console

I have deleted my "about" page in wordpress. My SEO Ultimate plugin now shows me a 404 error (I guess the google bots are trying to crawl it but can't find it). How to fix this - I'm not planing on using an "about" page any more? I also use a Google Sitemap plugin - so should I remove this plugin and only use the google webmaster tools? Thanks!

Comment: Consider removing it from the trash as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the links pointing to the 'about' page, otherwise bots will continue attempting to crawl the 'about' page, which returns a 404 error, as it no longer exists.